# How to extract and sum unique words from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, unique

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animals': [['dog','cat','snake','lion','tiger'], 
                  ['dog','moose','alligator','lion','tiger'], 
                  ['eagle','moose','alligator','lion','tiger'],
                  ['cat','alligator','lion']]})
```

I need to extract every single unique animal and sum the number of occurrences.
The output should be something like:

```
dog             2  
cat             2  
snake           1  
lion            4  
tiger           3  
moose           2  
alligator       3  
eagle           1
```

Similar to what df.value_counts() does.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `explode` and `value_counts`:

```
df.animals.explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
lion         4
tiger        3
alligator    3
moose        2
cat          2
dog          2
eagle        1
snake        1
Name: animals, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

One way with `Counter` + `chain`

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['animals'])))

dog          2
cat          2
snake        1
lion         4
tiger        3
moose        2
alligator    3
eagle        1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

A map/reduce approach

```
reduce(Counter.__add__, map(Counter, df.animals))
```

Or, to reduce the number of iterations

```
reduce(lambda a,b: Counter(a) + Counter(b), df.animals)
```

---

```
>>> pd.Series(res)

dog          2
cat          2
snake        1
lion         4
tiger        3
moose        2
alligator    3
eagle        1
dtype: int64
```

(Remember to import `reduce` first: `from functools import reduce` as it was removed as a built-in function in python3).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```py
bb = [val for in_arr in df['animals'].tolist() for val in in_arr]
Counter(bb)
```